# Undefined Twig Filter

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Twig in a standalone PHP app.  So my composer only has this requirement: `"twig/twig": "^3.6"`.

I initialize twig, and then add custom filter like so:

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('templates');
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
    'cache' => 'tmp/cache',
]);

$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('rot13', function ($string) {
    return str_rot13($string);
}));
```

In my templates, I always get Unknown Filter error whenever I try to use the filter in `{{ 'MYNAME' | rot13 }}`

Also tried with Function, but getting similar Unknown Function error.

Am I missing something?

This is the error on the page:

```
Unknown "rot13" filter. [/myfiles/templates/tester.html:26]

[vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php:562] Twig\ExpressionParser->getFilterNodeClass('rot13',26)
[vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php:547] Twig\ExpressionParser->parseFilterExpressionRaw(TwigNodeExpressionConstantExpression::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php:405] Twig\ExpressionParser->parseFilterExpression(TwigNodeExpressionConstantExpression::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php:288] Twig\ExpressionParser->parsePostfixExpression(TwigNodeExpressionConstantExpression::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php:177] Twig\ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression()
[vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php:72] Twig\ExpressionParser->getPrimary()
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php:127] Twig\ExpressionParser->parseExpression()
[vendor/twig/twig/src/TokenParser/ForTokenParser.php:42] Twig\Parser->subparse([TwigTokenParserForTokenParser::__set_state([]),'decideForFork'])
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php:170] Twig\TokenParser\ForTokenParser->parse(TwigToken::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/TokenParser/BlockTokenParser.php:47] Twig\Parser->subparse([TwigTokenParserBlockTokenParser::__set_state([]),'decideBlockEnd'],true)
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php:170] Twig\TokenParser\BlockTokenParser->parse(TwigToken::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php:83] Twig\Parser->subparse(NULL,false)
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php:491] Twig\Parser->parse(TwigTokenStream::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php:519] Twig\Environment->parse(TwigTokenStream::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php:351] Twig\Environment->compileSource(TwigSource::__set_state([]))
[vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php:312] Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('__TwigTemplate_9fcd4d27f601c5dddfd436979e4446b0','admin/classlist.html')
```

Comment: FIxed code.  I had a use \Twig|twigFilter at the top.  And the Error does say Unknown "rot13" filter.

Comment: How are you rendering the template? With the current posted code I'm not able to reproduce the error - [demo](https://www.darkbee.be/twig/filter.php)

Comment: In the template, as I mentioned I have {{ 'STRING' | rot13 }}.  To ensure my syntax is correct, I checked for {{ 'STRING' | lower }} and this correctly produces 'string'.

Comment: Yes, but how are you rendering the template? Are you using `$twig->render(...)`?

Comment: DOH!!!  That is EXACTLY the right question :-).  I had TWO places where $twig was used.  and I incorrectly added the filter to the wrong one.  Cl;aned up now.

Comment: That's what I figured. To answer your question to my question, yes you can also do `$template = $twig->loadTemplate(...); $template->display(...)`, but this should have the same effect as `render`, but glad you've figured it out

Answer (score 0):

User error.  There were two `$twig` instances, filters were added to one instance and rendered using the other one.  Thanks to @DarkBee for asking the right question :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('rot13', function ($string) {
    return str_rot13($string);
}));
```

Maybe he's just not able to resolve the class path. Works in my environment

Comment: Tried this one too, still Unknown "rot13" filter

Comment: If this were true then OP would get an entirely different error e.g. `Fatal error: Class "xxxxx" not found`